# jQuery bookmarklet textnode not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml, textnode

```
$('.messages').children().each(function() { 
   var textNode = $(this); 
   textNode.text(
      textNode.text().replace("hi", "<img src='http://stupidknews.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/smiley-face.jpg' style='height:10px;'>")
   ); 
});`
```

I have that, it replaces the text in all classes with `messages` fine, but it replaces it with text, not with actual HTML.

How to make it work now!

Answer (score 0):

You might need `html()` instead of `text();`

```
textNode.html(
   textNode.text().replace("hi", "<img src='http://stupidknews.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/smiley-face.jpg' style='height:10px;'>")
);
```